# Update post date of page when Visitor access that page?

Tags: date

How to update post date of page to real time when Visitor access that page?

Example: I write a post on May 28, 2013. And now, when I visit that post, it will change may 28 to June 8.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the action `the_post` (you get the post as parameter here) and run `wp_update_post()`. Make sure to clean up the *date* properties and not to run on the admin side or when a post is called in a widget:

```
is_admin() or add_action( 'the_post', function( $post ) {

    if ( ! is_singular() or ! is_main_query() )
        return;

    $post->post_date     = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $post->post_date_gmt = '';

    wp_update_post( $post );
});
```

**But** now you get a write operation on *every single request*. This will slow down your site. I wouldn’t do that.

Comment: Thank you ! If this slow down your site, I want to update date time only 1 times per day. How to do this ? Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

You could use wp_update_post in your page template or php page you are using to view the page to update the date of the page everytime it is viewed.

Comment: Can you help me, please ? I am not coder. So, I don't understand !

Comment: Sorry had been away, I think you already got the answer from the above since you accepted it.